# installing java on centos with alternatives

Tags: java, linux, java-8, centos, centos7

I want to upgrade java version on my CentOS (previously 1.8.0_144, now 1.8.0.201).
I used following command:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/java 180201
```

Now I get this:

```
    [root@centos java]# alternatives --display java
java - status is auto.
 link currently points to /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/java
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java - priority 180144
 slave ControlPanel: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/ControlPanel
 slave javaws: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/javaws
 slave jcontrol: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/jcontrol
 slave jjs: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/jjs
 slave keytool: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/keytool
 slave orbd: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/orbd
 slave pack200: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/pack200
 slave policytool: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/policytool
 slave rmid: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/rmid
 slave rmiregistry: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/rmiregistry
 slave servertool: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/servertool
 slave tnameserv: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/tnameserv
 slave unpack200: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/unpack200
 slave java.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/java.1
 slave javaws.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/javaws.1
 slave jjs.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/jjs.1
 slave keytool.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/keytool.1
 slave orbd.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/orbd.1
 slave pack200.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/pack200.1
 slave policytool.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/policytool.1
 slave rmid.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/rmid.1
 slave rmiregistry.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/rmiregistry.1
 slave servertool.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/servertool.1
 slave tnameserv.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/tnameserv.1
 slave unpack200.1: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/man/man1/unpack200.1
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/java - priority 180201
 slave ControlPanel: (null)
 slave javaws: (null)
 slave jcontrol: (null)
 slave jjs: (null)
 slave keytool: (null)
 slave orbd: (null)
 slave pack200: (null)
 slave policytool: (null)
 slave rmid: (null)
 slave rmiregistry: (null)
 slave servertool: (null)
 slave tnameserv: (null)
 slave unpack200: (null)
 slave java.1: (null)
 slave javaws.1: (null)
 slave jjs.1: (null)
 slave keytool.1: (null)
 slave orbd.1: (null)
 slave pack200.1: (null)
 slave policytool.1: (null)
 slave rmid.1: (null)
 slave rmiregistry.1: (null)
 slave servertool.1: (null)
 slave tnameserv.1: (null)
 slave unpack200.1: (null)
Current `best' version is /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/java.
```

Also, many slave links from /etc/alternatives folder are still pointing to old java version, like

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   38 Mar 17 14:12 keytool -> /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/keytool
```

Shouldn't those slave links change automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The following command will allow you to set the default Java version to use in CentOS:

```
$ sudo alternatives --config java
```

If successful, you should see `1.8.0_201` as the new default version:

```
$ java -version
```